Force pulling specific objects together
I'm new to blender, sorry if it is's a trivial question:
I have 3 cubes, A, B, C. I want to set a spring to pull together A and B, and a string that pulls together B and C. I tried to add rigid body constraint "Generic spring" but it seems to only push away, not pulling. I also tried to set a force field that pulls just the connecting point of the cubes, but I got confused at setting collections and my force fields are pulling the 3rd cube too.
Can anyone help me with baby steps?
Thanks!
Update:
A visual to explain: at the start there are 2 forces that pull the object in the middle to resting position


I hope you already know how to create a rigid body and add a constraint.
When you use the spring constraint it starts simulating in its resting position. You have to animate or move the connected objects before they can be pulled together.
If by 'string' you mean something like a rope you can build it with multiple rigid bodies and constraints. There is no simple 'string' constraint. Unless you mean just limiting their distance then you can just use a slider or generic constraint.
I do not understand what you were trying with the force fields but if you want to limit what objects they effect you can enable and set their 'Max Distance' setting.
I made a small example scene with what I think you meant to archive. I animated the cubes A and B to be separated so they will be pulled together again.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1re0KjY-B1nPCYkVQOU6pEtosgNdq__Sy/view?usp=sharing

Hi,
Thank you for the answer! I am looking for something a bit different.
I have stretched springs between A and B, and B and C, and when I start the animation they pull together. I'm updating the original post with an image for clarification

I think one option is to set up the resting position in keyframe one, then set the position I want is at keyframe 20 and disable animated after. Based on your answer.
